# QGIS - eliminate srs from BBOX?

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to render an ArcGIS WFS service within QGIS.  Through no fault of QGIS, the service is failing because of the 5th BBOX parameter (urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326):

```
https://canttouchthis/arcgis/services/CALIX_TEST/CALIX_ANNOTATIONS/MapServer/WFSServer?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=CALIX_TEST_CALIX_ANNOTATIONS:polygons&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326&BBOX=4324959.29130463115870953,-12827075.77402532286942005,4325046.08483351208269596,-12826893.6371572520583868,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326 - server replied: Bad Request
```

When I remove `,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326` it works fine -- ESRI WFS isn't equipped to deal with it:

```
<![CDATA[
KVP parser : parameter 'bbox' '4324959.29130463115870953,-12827075.77402532286942005,4325046.08483351208269596,-12826893.6371572520583868,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::432' not recognized.
]]>
```

Once I remove the 5th parameter I get the desired feature data.

**QUESTION:** Can QGIS be configured to NOT provide the srs in the bbox?

**ANSWER:** Supply a filter (e.g. 1=1).

Comment: Answer appears to be no: https://github.com/ccrook/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/python/ext-libs/owslib/feature/__init__.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, QGIS cannot be configured to suppress the 5th BBOX parameter but if you supply a dummy filter (e.g. 1=1) it forces QGIS to use a POST instead of a GET.  This will eliminate the incompatible BBOX allowing you to view ESRI features within QGIS via WFS services.